# Custom MapView Class Swift

Tags: swift, mkmapview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm having some major issues and could use some help. I'm using some code from the company What3Words. They created a custom class:

```
open class MapView: MKMapView, MKMapViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
//all their code is here
}
```

My goal is to use a tap gesture in order to acquire a lat/long from the map. I can do this incredibly easily when using a MapViewKit drop in and I make the object conform to MKMapView!

```
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    @IBAction func tapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("hey")
    let tap = sender
        let coord = tap.location(in: map)
        print(coord)
        print(tap.location(in: self))
        print(tap.location(in: map))
        map.convert(coord, to: map)
        print(map.convert(coord, to: map))
        
    }

}
```

But, if I conform it MKMapView! I can't access any of the specialty code within the open class.
and if I conform it to the open class I don't know how to use my tap gesture.

I'm supposed to call this code below in whatever VC I want the map to appear in:

```
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let map = MapViewController(frame: view.frame)
    map.set(api: api)
    map.set(center: "school.truck.lunch", latitudeSpan: 0.05, longitudeSpan: 0.05)
    map.showsUserLocation = true

    
    map.onError = { error in
      self.showError(error: error)
    }
    
    self.view = map
}

  // MARK: Show an Error
  
  /// display an error using a UIAlertController, error messages conform to CustomStringConvertible
  func showError(error: Error) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: String(describing: error), preferredStyle: .alert)
      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
      self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
  }
```

Any idea how I can get a tap gesture to work while still using this special class? I feel like I've tried everything. UGH!! Please assist.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do it is to add the following to your ViewController:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let location = touches.first?.location(in: map) {
      map.screenCoordsToWords(point: location) { square in
        print(square.words ?? "")
      }
    }
  }
```

And in your MapView class add this:

```
func screenCoordsToWords(point: CGPoint, completion: @escaping (W3WSquare) -> () ) {
  let coordinates = convert(point, toCoordinateFrom: self)
  self.api?.convertTo3wa(coordinates: coordinates, language: "en") { square, error in
    if let s = square {
      completion(s)
    }
  }
}
```

But doing it this way can lead to confusion between MKMapView's touch event handler and your view controller.  Depending on what you're trying to accomplish this might be okay, or not okay.

If it's an issue, you can *instead* attach a gesture recognizer inside your MapView, but there is a trick to prevent overriding the MKMapView's built in double tap recogniser:

```
  func addGesture() {
    /// when the user taps the map this is called and it gets the square info
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    
    // A kind of tricky thing to make sure double tap doesn't trigger single tap in MKMapView
    let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:nil)
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
    tap.require(toFail: doubleTap)
    
    tap.delegate = self
    
    addGestureRecognizer(tap)
  }

  
  @objc func tapped(_ gestureRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self)
    let coordinates = convert(location, toCoordinateFrom: self)
    api?.convertTo3wa(coordinates: coordinates, language: "en") { square, error in
      if let s = square {
        print(s.words ?? "")
      }
    }
  }
```

Then in your ViewController's viewDidLoad, set it up:

```
map.addGesture()
```

Comment: This worked amazingly. Thanks. If I wanted to highlight the tile that I tap a different color, would I just place .addOverlay and .removeOverlay inside of the @objc func tapped?

Comment: Assuming that by "tile" you mean the square around the three word address, I think you'd might create a new overlay for the square you want to highlight, or modify the grid drawing algorithm in the current grid to highlight a particular square.  But yes, I don't see why you couldn't call something to set that in the `tapped` function.
Incidentally, the `square` parameter of the closure contains the coordinates (`southWestBounds` + `northEastBounds`) of the square boundaries for the selected three word address.